# Edit Meta.db in influxdb

Tags: macos, influxdb, execute

How can I edit meta.db in influxdb? I am getting `8086: bind: address already in use`.
This ip is only available in meta.db which I found by influxd config on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can change port from `8086` to something else in `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` if its already in use. Or you can kill the service that is using port `8086`.
you can check with, `sudo lsof -n -i :8086 | grep LISTEN` who is using port `8086`